# Should you provide the copy constructor or the move constructor with a default argument?

Tags: c++

Suppose you have the following class:

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    ...

    A (T const &t) 
    {
        ...
    }

    A (T &&t) noexcept
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Now suppose I want to provide a default argument to one of these (i.e., `= T{}`). Which is more efficient/consistent to default, the copy or the move? Does it even matter? My gut says it doesn't matter performance wise, which leads me to think it would be more consistent to default the copy since you should not bind a temporary to an r-value.

Thoughts?

Comment: What is the purpose of having a default argument?  Also, FWIW, you should try to follow the rule of zero and either not write any of the special member functions or declare them as `default`.

Comment: Those are not copy / move constructors.

Comment: A temporary *is* an r-value, there's no problem binding an r-value reference to one.

Comment: Working on my own implementation of a result<T>, which is similar to other attempts at expected<T>, etc... for error handling. The implementation is similar to a std::optional, so things like the rule of zero do not apply. The default argument is so that you can create a result<T>{} without having to say something like result<myclass>{myclass{}}. Also note that this needs to be AUTOSAR compliant, so tricks like emplace are not allowed (as you cannot use forwarding references in constructors).

Answer (score 0):

Those are not copy / move constructors, so you don't have to use a reference *at all*.

Assuming you have distinguished those cases to elide copying `t` if you can, just have one construtor

```
template<typename T>
class A
{
    ...

    /* explicit ? */ A (T t = {}) 
    {
        ...
    }
};
```

Comment: @RianQuinn That's not what I meant. You can `new (ptr) (std::move(t))` in this, you don't need to distinguish `const T &` and `T &&`

Comment: That would call T's move constructor even if a copy is required. Once again, I am implementing something like std::optional, so I have to respect the copy/move semantics of T. For more information, please see the implementation of std::optional